# How can my NXT client/server send to multiple addresses paying one 1 transaction fee?

Tags: multi-signature, nxt, faucets

I know bitcoind lets you have multiple outputs (sending to multiple address) via the command line. Does NXT support this feature? I want to create a faucet application where I can send to multiple addresses via a cron while only paying 1 transaction fee only.

Also what is the max number of addresses you can send to via NXT if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the protocol level Nxt doesn't support sending multiple payments with one transaction. Future versions may have this feature added.